# What is the difference between the active connections from nginx status page and the connections displayed by command 'netstat -an'?

Tags: nginx, tcp, websocket

I'm a beginner to **Nginx**. Currently we are looking for a way to improve the **Nginx**'s performance to support thousands of concurrent connections for our application. However I'm kind of running into a problem when I am running performance test. We are using **Nginx** as an reverse proxy to our **Websockets** application. I'm currently using [tcpkali](https://github.com/machinezone/tcpkali) to generate load for our Nginx server. The command I issued is as following:

`tcpkali -c1000 --ws 192.168.0.180:8010 --duration 3h`

Theoretically there should be 1000 connections established to the Nginx server. But when I check it from the Nginx [status page](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/nginx/status-page/), it only displays there are two active connections as following:

```
Active connections: 2 
server accepts handled requests
 26 26 52 
Reading: 0 Writing: 2 Waiting: 0
```

It shows there are 1000 connections when I issued the this command from terminal 
 `netstat -an|grep :8010|grep ESTABLISHED|wc -l`.
Why the active connections number I get from these two places are different? I'm so confusing.